# Hibernate HSQL select new with nested List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I've searched for this problem and have been stuck for the past couple of days so i'm hoping you can help out. I will try to summarize the problem I run into with a basic concept because then I can just apply that to my more complex problem.

I have 2 entity objects: Student and Course. Notice the student entity creates a table with 3 columns and has an additional property for 'amount'. The idea here is I don't want to store the aggregate that I will perform when I execute my query. So the student buys several courses and each course has a cost. I want to sum up the total cost so that it is in the same level in json (see desired outcome).

Where I am stuck is in my select query. Everything works when I remove the a.course. My json shows the aggregate and all is well. But obviously the list of course is missing. So my overall question is how should my select query look when I have a nested list object embedded in my query?

`select new Student(a.id, a.name, a.course,`

Desired outcome:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Billy"
"course":
     {[
         "id" : 1,
         "courseName" : "Math",
         "cost" : 12.99
       ],[
         "id" : 2,
         "courseName" : "Science",
         "cost" : 15.99
       ]
     }
"amount" : 28.98

}
```

```
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator="PRIVATE_SEQ"
    )
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "native",
        strategy = "native"
    )
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 25)
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private List<Course> course;

private BigDecimal amount;

public Student(Long id, String name,  List<Course> course, BigDecimal amount) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.course = course;
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

}

```
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator="PRIVATE_SEQ"
    )
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "native",
        strategy = "native"
    )
private long id;

@Column(name = "coursename", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String courseName;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private Student student;

@Column(name = "cost", nullable = false)
private BigDecimal cost;

public Course(Long id, String courseName, BigDecimal cost) {
    this.id = id;
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.cost = cost;
}
```

```
List<Student> students = session
        .createQuery(" select new Student(a.id, a.name, a.course, SUM(CASE WHEN b.cost <> 0 THEN b.cost ELSE 0 END)) from Student a "
                + "Left join fetch Course b on b.id = d.budget "
                + "group by b.id ")
        .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that with a subquery, but it's simply not possible to use the JPQL constructor expression with collections. It only works with scalars.

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

Blaze-Persistence is a query builder on top of JPA which supports many of the advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model. I created Entity Views on top of it to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A DTO mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(Student.class)
interface StudentDto {
    long getId();
    String getName();
    List<CourseDto> getCourses();
    @Mapping("SUM(courses.cost) OVER (PARTITION BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)")
    BigDecimal getAmount();
}
@EntityView(Course.class)
interface CourseDto {
    long getId();
    String getCourseName();
    BigDecimal getCost();
}
```

I'm using window functions here, not sure if HSQLDB supports that, but you could also use a subquery or simply choose a different fetch strategy for the collection to make aggregations work properly.

```
@EntityView(Student.class)
interface StudentDto {
    long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping(fetch = SUBSELECT)
    List<CourseDto> getCourses();
    @Mapping("SUM(courses.cost)")
    BigDecimal getAmount();
}
```

What I don't understand is, why you want to compute the amount in SQL when you are about to fetch all courses anyway. You could simply calculate the amount in Java like this:

```
@EntityView(Student.class)
interface StudentDto {
    long getId();
    String getName();
    List<CourseDto> getCourses();
    default BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return getCourses().stream().map(CourseDto::getCost).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`StudentDto dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, StudentDto.class, id);`

But the Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

It will only fetch the mappings that you tell it to fetch